# Multiple jAppletForm in a Java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, frame, japplet

I've created a new Java project without main class in NetBeans and then I've added a jApplet Form (let's call it `MainWindow.java`) to my project package. After that, I've added few other jApplet Forms that represent different "pages" of my applet application to my package using the GUI builder of NetBeans.

When I run my applet, I can see the `MainWindow` form with some buttons, label, etc. on the AppletViewer just fine.

Now, I want to make an event when one of my buttons on my `MainWindow` is pressed, to show another jApplet Form that I've created earlier and show that form instead of the MainWindow form. I'm trying to create a simple navigation system in my jApplet, and I don't know how to make it efficiently!

Can anyone help me with the code that I should write in the MouseClicked event of my button to make it show another form?

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a simple navigation system in my jApplet"*  Don't do that.  HTML links should be used for navigation, for accessibility, as well as a dozen other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't (or shouldn't) design applets like this. There is no effective means to switch from one applet to another.

Instead, you should create one master applet and using something like `CardLayout`, design separate forms using one thing like `JPanel`

You'd then able to switch the forms using the `CardLayout` manager as needed